Unable to access CDI with spring/joinfaces war on Wildfly server
I used spring 3.3.1, joinfaces 5.3.1, wildfly-27.0.1.Final
The maven build is made without problem. When I deploy the application on Tomcat 10 it works fine, but when I deploy it on wildfly 27, it fail and the "Unable to access CDI" occurs like this :
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access CDI    at jakarta.enterprise.api//jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.CDI.lambda$getCDIProvider$0(CDI.java:98)   at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:403)  at jakarta.enterprise.api//jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.CDI.getCDIProvider(CDI.java:98)    at jakarta.enterprise.api//jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.CDI.current(CDI.java:65)
My pom.xml is :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-model href=""?>
<project xmlns="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    
    <groupId>ma.gov.adii</groupId>
    <artifactId>springbootprime</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>springbootprime</name>
    <description>Spring Boot Prime Faces</description>
    
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <joinfaces.version>5.3.0</joinfaces.version>
        <jakarta.validation-api.version>3.0.2</jakarta.validation-api.version>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
             <dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
                <version>${jakarta.validation-api.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
                <artifactId>joinfaces-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${joinfaces.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
             <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
              </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
           <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
           <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

The Wildfly log is like this :
2024-07-04 15:59:57,934 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 86) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."thymeleaf-tutorial-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".undertow-deployment: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."thymeleaf-tutorial-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access CDI
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@27.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:90)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access CDI
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:257)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@27.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@27.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access CDI
    at jakarta.enterprise.api//jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.CDI.lambda$getCDIProvider$0(CDI.java:98)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:403)
    at jakarta.enterprise.api//jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.CDI.getCDIProvider(CDI.java:98)
    at jakarta.enterprise.api//jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.CDI.current(CDI.java:65)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.module.web.servlet.WeldInitialListener.contextInitialized(WeldInitialListener.java:88)
    at org.jboss.weld.spi@5.0.0.SP3//org.jboss.weld.servlet.api.helpers.ForwardingServletListener.contextInitialized(ForwardingServletListener.java:34)
    at deployment.thymeleaf-tutorial-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.EnhancedListener.onStartup(EnhancedListener.java:70)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:204)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@27.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1435)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@27.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1435)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@27.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1435)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@27.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1435)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:255)
    ... 10 more


I don't know anything about JoinFaces, but does it work with Jakarta EE 10?

I recently ran into this issue, and the solution was to add the following exclusion to the org.joinfaces:primefaces-spring-boot-starter dependency within pom.xml:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

